# UIActionSheet checkmark

Tags: ios, select, uiactionsheet, checkmark

I need to mark selected button in UIActionSheet.

How can I add checkmark in UIActionSheet button?

Is there some way specific for UIActionSheet, without standard adding image inside button.

Comment: Can't be done with UIActionSheet. Find a 3rd party replacement.

Answer (score 5):

```
otherButtonTitles:@"√ 1", @"  2",
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from iOS 8.0 you can use `UIAlertController`. In `UIAlertController`, each button item is know as `UIAlertAction` which add accordingly. `UIAlertAction` contains a runtime property called image which you can set as per your need.

```
UIAlertActioin *action1 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"1" style: UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:(void (^)(UIAlertAction *action)) {
    [action setValue:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your-image-name"] forKey:@"_image"];
}];
```

Comment: Xcode 7.2.1 won't compile it because `UIAlertAction` has no method `setImage:`