# How to add a check mark to a selected option in Action Sheet IOS option in react native?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I was working on react native app in which I need to change few values in a component after user has selected an option.

To select an option I open action sheet in IOS. Now I wanted to show the current selected option in the Action Sheet by adding a check mark.

I was able to see this in podcast app of iphone as attached in the screenshot.

I was also able to see few native implementations of this in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647039/how-to-add-uiactionsheet-button-check-mark) , but I wanted this to work in case of react native.

Can someone please help?

[image]

Comment: Can you show some code? What is your exact problem?

Comment: Exact problem is adding check mark (as you can see in the image) to the current selected index.

Comment: it is too broad, what did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to do is to use destructiveButtonIndex property of the Action Sheet. It cannot add a check mark, but at least will change the colour of the option to orange. In this case, user can know which one is checked before.